# D3D11 MultisampleEnable and AntialiasedLineEnable affecting line rendering

Tags: graphics, direct3d, antialiasing, direct3d11

Microsoft D3D11 [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ns-d3d11-d3d11_rasterizer_desc#remarks) for **D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC** structure writes:

> The settings of the MultisampleEnable and AntialiasedLineEnable members apply only to multisample antialiasing (MSAA) render targets (that is, render targets with sample counts greater than 1).

Should I expect line rendering to be affected by those members only when I am rendering to a multisampled target and not when I am rendering on a "single sampled" one?

When drawing a Line Strip I found line rasterization to be affected by those settings:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: It's my understanding that the `AntialiasedLineEnable` member in **D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC** only applies if doing line drawing and `MultisampleEnable` is FALSE.

Comment: @MaicoDeBlasio and how do you interpret the quote from the documentation? to me that means that both those members are meaningful only if the drawing is happening on a multisampled render target.

Comment: The description for `AntialiasedLineEnable` is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ns-d3d11-d3d11_rasterizer_desc) for **D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC** .
It's the same for **D3D12_RASTERIZER_DESC** in DirectX 12.

Comment: The documentation (the same you and I posted) states:

_"The settings of the MultisampleEnable and AntialiasedLineEnable members apply only to multisample antialiasing (MSAA) render targets (that is, render targets with sample counts greater than 1)."_

So my question is: Does that means that `AntialiasedLineEnable` and `MultisampleEnable` are ignored when drawing on a **not multisampled** target?
If that's the case, why does my lines are rasterized differently depending on those settings even if I'm rendering on a target with sample count = 1?

Comment: Ok it seems that if sample count > 1,  and if `MultisampleEnable` is false, then `AntialiasedLineEnable` acts as a toggle between aliased and alpha-antialiased line rendering. If `MultisampleEnable` is true, then you always get quadrilateral line rendering and `AntialiasedLineEnable` is ignored.

Comment: Exactly. Please take a look at the image I posted: you see 2 lines clearly rasterized using different algorithms. The images are taken from the same application launched twice: first attempt drawing the line with a **RasterizerState** with both `AALineEnables` and `MSEnable` set to `true` and the second attempt using `false` for both (it's all in the image). The **target sample count is 1** for both the attempts, so I expected the line rasterization to be the same regardless of those settings. Why is the rasterization  different?

Comment: If your table captures of Rasterizer State 152 (where Multisample and LineAA are true) and RS 648 (where Multisample and LineAA are false) were both generated from a single sample target, then I agree with you. The line segment on the left is clearly being anti-aliased, which contradicts the (somewhat confusing) Microsoft docs. I can only speculate that the runtime isn't behaving as Microsoft says. The differences in feature-level behaviour (that are also alluded to in the docs) further complicates matters!